# Strange behavior when I use `never extends never` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on typescript-challenge 399. Tuple Filter (https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00399-hard-tuple-filter/README.md)

This is my code

```js
type FilterOut<T extends any[], F, Res extends unknown[] = []> = 
  T extends [infer X, ...infer Y]
  ? X extends F
    ? FilterOut<Y, F, Res>
    : FilterOut<Y, F, [...Res, X]>
  : Res

type t0 = FilterOut<['a', 'b'],'a'> // ['b'] -> Just as I expected
type t1 = FilterOut<[never], never> // never -> But I expect []
type t2 = FilterOut<[never, 'a'], never> // never -> But I expect ['a']
```

As you can see, t1 and t2 are different from my expectation. I know if I replace `X extends F` to `[X] extends [F]`, then I can fix this question.

However, I just wonder why we will obtain `never` in the first version code? Is this due to some weird properties of `never`?

Here I try another thing about `never`, and I think it maybe due to the same reason from the previous question.

```js
type t3 = never extends never ? 1 : 2 // 1 -> As I expected
type test<T, F> =
  T extends F 
    ? 1
    : 2 

type t4 = test<never, never> // never -> But I expect 1
```

Can anybody help me or give me some documentation about this question! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `test` is a *distributive* conditional type, and `never` is considered the empty union, so it will output `never` no matter what.  `t3` is not distributive over unions.  See the linked questions and answers for details and more information.